# Cardano Pre Production Testnet TrConnectError

Tags: cardano

Since the documention of the cardano developer portal is outdated (old testnet) i researched and now know about the new testnets documented here https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html and on Github.

I followed the tutorial on the documentation https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano about running the node for the testnet, but instead of using the deprecated files i used the new enviroment files for the pre production testnet.

Now i cant sync the network.

I get the following info over and over again:

```
TrConnectError (Just 127.0.0.1:1337) 3.72.231.105:30000 Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})

TracePromoteColdFailed 50 0 3.72.231.105:30000 160.633570297628s Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

TraceGovernorWakeup
TracePublicRootsRequest 100 1
TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preprod-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30000]
TracePublicRootResult "preprod-node.world.dev.cardano.org" [(3.72.231.105,60)]
TracePublicRootsResults (fromList []) 9 512s
```

[console info from the node, same es in the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08CQ0.png)

I can get the sync status which looks like the first time running like this:

```
{
    "block": 0,
    "epoch": 0,
    "era": "Byron",
    "hash": "9ad7ff320c9cf74e0f5ee78d22a85ce42bb0a487d0506bf60cfb5a91ea4497d2",
    "slot": 0,
    "syncProgress": "0.01"
}
```

I tried it with the devnet, and preview testnet too - didn't work either.

Cardano node version (currently the newest):

```
cardano-node 1.35.3 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev ea6d78c775d0f70dde979b52de022db749a2cc32
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the node with "--host-addr 0.0.0.0". For example:

cardano-node run --config $HOME/cardano/preprod/config.json 
--database-path $HOME/cardano/db 
--socket-path $HOME/cardano/db/node.socket 
--host-addr 0.0.0.0 
--port 1337 
--topology $HOME/cardano/preprod/topology.json

Comment: 127.0.0.1 means that it listens to localhots only, 0.0.0.0 means I listen to anyone